# Считывание значения TextBox из другого приложения в С#

Tags: c#

Требуется автоматизировать процесс лазерной перфорации тысяч файлов в EzCAD с помощью приложения C# WFA.

У EzCAD есть TextBox, значение которого увеличивается после завершения прожигания.

Получается нужно приложение, которое  проимитирует нажатия клавиш  для загрузить и прожечь и когда заметит увеличение TextBox повторит эти действия для следующего из тысяч файлов.

Знаю как послать команду загрузить и прожечь, а что требуется для считывания этого TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала тебе нужен инспектор с помощью которого ты сможешь изучить интерфейс и найти необходимые классы с которыми ты можешь взаимодействовать.

Для этой цели можно поставить себе `AutoIt`.

Дальше у вас такие пути:

1. Через WinAPI найти необходимые окна и мониторить их - это геморрой.
2. Написать скрипт на AutoIt, который решит поставленную задачу
3. Тоже самое, что и второй пункт, но подрубив либу к C#. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26807344/4244707) показано как. [Тут](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/ru/examples/-/AutoItX3/-/php-autoitx3-class-examples.html) примеры

P.S Если AutoIt не нашел элементы интерфейса, значит используется какой-то хитрый фреймворк => никак промониторить нельзя.